# Convert a stream of bytes to a String (UTF-8 encoded)

Tags: java, android, utf-8, inputstream

I have a stream of bytes (given by a BufferedInputStream) which represents a sequence of UTF-8 strings. The protocol is a little crappy becauses it uses 0xFF between commands, which implies that the whole stream is not a valid UTF-8 string, only the parts between the 0xFF are.

**How can I extract those UTF-8 strings.**

I don’t think BufferedReader would work, because the 0xFF will mess up everything and I have found no byte array to UTF-8 string conversion function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[byte[] to String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29)

So would be `new String(bytes, "UTF-8");`

You would need to filter the Stream beforehand though.

Comment: Thanks :-)  By the way, in order to convert the Stream into a byte[] I filled an ArrayList<Byte> by reading the bytes one by one, and then I converted it to a byte[]. Do you think there is a simpler way to do this? (I don’t want to do something ugly like declaring a new byte[1024] and hoping that the input will not be more than 1024 bytes)

Comment: You can use the ByteBuffer http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

Comment: This does not seem to grow automatically when the ByteBuffer is full, so I do not really see the interest. I will still have to declare an arbitrary size and hope that my input is not too big.

Comment: You could use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html